# margin and padding problems in IE and Firefox

Tags: css

Okay guys, I have two CSS problems in different browsers:

1) Both in IE and in Firefox, the `20px` of `padding` (top) looks different. In IE and Firefox `fullscreen_block` appears closer to the bottom than in Safari and Chrome.

```
.fullscreen_block {
padding: 20px 0 0 20px;
text-align: center;
}
```

2) Only in IE, `margin-right` of `right-sidebar-block` appears a lot closer to the left side of the page than intended.

```
.right-sidebar-block {
width: 120px;
float: right;
margin-top: 19px;
margin-right: 270px;
margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

Does anybody have an idea how to fix this?
Thanks!!!

EDIT: This is the html for `.right.sidebar-block` It just contains two things, Facebook and Twitter Box:

```
<div class="right-sidebar-block">
<iframe style="width:178px;height:271.0px;background:#ffffff; border:1px solid #d9d9d9 !important;border-radius:6px; margin-left:0px; margin-top: 310px; position:absolute !important; z-index:9999999 !important;" src="..." scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"><a href="" class="fbook"></a></iframe>
<a class="twitter-timeline" 
width="100"
height="295" 
href="https://twitter.com/" 
data-widget-id="52722121576371329536">Tweets by</a>
<script>...</script> 
</div>
```

As to `fullscreen_block`, this is a big `div` that contains several other `divs` with `forms` etc.

Comment: What is HTML structure? Have you a demo? Please put your codes in JSFiddle.

Comment: Even better: put the code in a runnable code snippet inside your question. Whichever, we need the HTML code.

Comment: Do your results get better by applying `box-sizing: border-box` to the elements?

Answer (score 0):

Use normalizer or any browser reset stylesheet. Otherwise in most cases:

html, body{ margin: 0; padding: 0 }

rules should do it.

But via browser reset sheets you could avoid a bunch of problems like this.